# Assign converters and default on RestController Get request with DTO parameter

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I have an endpoint with lots of fields so I have enclosed them in one single class and used `@ModelAttribute`

Endpoint:

```
@GetMapping
    public Page<VtmsTaskDto> list(@ModelAttribute TaskFilter taskFilter) {
     // blabla logic
}
```

**TaskFilterDto.java**

```
@Getter @Setter
public class TaskFilterDto {
private String sortDto;
private ZonedDateTime creationDate;
... bunch of other filters
}
```

No I want to do some converters and assign default values on these props
something like `@JsonDeserialize(converter=CustomConverter.class)` or `@JsonProperty(default="someDefaultValue")`
But since the request uses default encoding url form encoded I can not use any of Jackson JSON annotations.

So I imagine **TaskFilterDto.java** class can something like this:

```
 public class TaskFilterDto {

            @Converter(SortStringToSortDto.class)
            @Default(value="creationDate")
            private SortDto sort;

            @Converter(ZonedDateTimeToLocalDateTime.class)
            private LocalDateTime creationDateInUTC;
            ... bunch of other filters
   }
```

Is there any proper solution to this or I am considering an invalid approach ?